# I am unable to build APK fron react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, apk

I am getting these error while creating apk

:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssetsFAILED 2.169s
:react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlinUP-TO-DATE 0.025s
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig 0.021s
:react-native-gradle-plugin:jarUP-TO-DATE   0.010s
:react-native-splash-screen:compileReleaseAidlNO-SOURCE 0.010s
:app:javaPreCompileRelease  0.009s
Explore timeline

Comment: Can you go to error logs and provide more information. Also add your PC details and react native details. Question is quite unclear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this [click hear](https://medium.com/geekculture/react-native-generate-apk-debug-and-release-apk-4e9981a2ea51)